# View output from shell command on a Django WebApp in realtime

Tags: python, django, shell

I trying to build a Web application with Django that must run a command on the server shell and show the output in realtime on the browser.

I need to be able to view the output and, if necessary, cancel execution.

I would like to know if I need to setup a websocket service or if there is a simpler way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done the same thing, but I guess you can do it like this:

1. First, when you run a command on the server, you need to save the output to database or file.
2. Second, you need a daemon in your front-end, it check the database or file every minutes or seconds through http. Once the daemon find something have changed, it will display it on the browser.
3. Finally, if you want to cancel it though browser, i think you should send some signal to backend, and check the signal in django app and maybe run some command through python. If you want to cancel the command though the server, it's may be as easy as `kill -9 pid`

About step 2, I recommend you use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)